# I am currently trying to create an program that can send data from browser to android app

Tags: java, websocket, okhttp, stomp

I am currently trying to create an program that can send data from browser to android app, in this I am successfully able to do so only from browser to Android Studio Virtual Machine. However I would like to send data from the browser to the app on my phone, how would I need to change my ADDRESS to make it work?

Edit: Do I have to use the same wifi to make it work?

```
 //<code>im</code> in address is the endpoint configured in server.
 //If you are using AVD provided by Android Studio, you should uncomment the upper address.
 //If you are using Genymotion, nothing else to do.



public class Const {
public static final String TAG = "xlui";
public static final String placeholder = "placeholder";
 
private static final String ADDRESS = "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/im/websocket";//for android vm
//public static final String address = "ws://10.0.3.2:8080/im/websocket";//for Genymotion

public static final String broadcast = "/broadcast";
public static final String broadcastResponse = "/b";
// replace {@code placeholder} with group id
public static final String group = "/group/" + placeholder;
public static final String groupResponse = "/g/" + placeholder;
public static final String chat = "/chat";
// replace {@code placeholder} with user id
public static final String chatResponse = "/user/" + placeholder + "/msg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dev usage I personally prefer the local solution. This means that you use the same WIFI as you server and use the public IP address of that server as IP.

For example your configuration looks like that (on local network site)
router is running on 10.0.0.1
server is running on 10.0.0.24
client is running on 10.0.0.50

so the web socket would run on `"ws://10.0.0.24:8080/im/websocket"`